# Change string type used for ‘print’ argument type coercion

Tags: python, unicode, compatibility, python-2.x, type-coercion

How can I convince Python 2's **`print` to coerce its arguments to `unicode`**?

The Python 2 `print` functionality, whether a statement or a function, evidently coerces its arguments to the bytes type, `str`:

```python
>>> import sys
>>> import io
>>> sys.version_info[0:2]
(2, 7)

>>> print >> sys.stderr, None
None
>>> print >> io.StringIO(), None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

Making `print` into a function doesn't help; the same internal argument handling seems to happen on Python 2 regardless:

```python
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import sys
>>> import io
>>> sys.version_info[0:2]
(2, 7)

>>> print(None, file=sys.stderr)
None
>>> print(None, file=io.StringIO())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

Since I want to replace the standard streams with `io.StringIO` instances (to make the code run in a test suite under Python 2 and Python 3), the above failure is stopping me dead.

Using an `io.BytesIO` instance would work on Python 2's `print`, but break on Python 3's `print`. And the goal is to make the code work with Unicode as much as possible, so `io.BytesIO` is not an acceptable solution for this purpose.

I need *every* output from `print` to be Unicode, not bytes.

How can I **change the type used by `print` for coercing its arguments for output**, and use the Unicode text type `unicode` instead?

Comment: A simple solution is to use `io.BytesIO()`

Comment: If you're running in Python's builtin `unittest` framework, using the `buffer` argument might do the job for you. Without that, I believe I have successfully replaced `sys.stdout` with a mock object that only requires one or two functions, but it's some time ago so I don't remember exactly.

Comment: have you tried `from python23compat import print`?

Comment: I got the same error with `io.StringIO` in python 2.7.. Switching to `StringIO.StringIO()` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Very messy but perhaps there's something useful in this:

```
import sys
import io

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    bytes_out = io.BytesIO()
    out_buffer = io.TextIOWrapper(bytes_out, encoding="utf-8")
else:
    out_buffer = io.BytesIO()

# print now supports all variants
print(None, file=out_buffer)
print(b"hello", file=out_buffer)
print("£", file=out_buffer)

out_buffer.flush()
out_buffer.seek(0)

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    my_unicode = out_buffer.read()
else:
    my_unicode = out_buffer.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

For print>> you need an object with a .write method which accepts strings. I don't think there is any other way.

You could create a wrapper to convert str to unicode

```
class a(object):
  def __init__(self, b):
    self.b=b
  def write(self, s):
    self.b.write(unicode(s,'utf-8'))

buf=io.StringIO()
print >> a(buf), '...'
```